# Deploy Tkinter : error loading Python dll/ LoadLibrary

Tags: python, tkinter, deployment, cx-freeze

I am trying to freeze my tkinter application. But I have this problem that suddenly appears. The apps I had freeze don't open either. How can I solve this problem?

[image: error]

I have a second question: if I freeze with cx_freeze, can I open it on another computer that doesn't have python?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [issue on Github](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10884),And I found a solution:

> Solution: paths were missing from my PATH. Using the Anaconda Prompt fixed the issue. Then I copied the anaconda paths from echo %PATH%, and I can now run it everywhere, after adjusting the local PATH.

---

> if I freeze with cx_freeze, can I open it on another computer that doesn't have python

If it could work normally in your PC, it could work well **mostly** on another computer with windows system.